# pyinstaller not loading a text file along with the exe created

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm not sure if this is a silly question.

Language - Python
Platform - Windows

I have a python code which reads a .csv file data and displays it in GUI designed in qt designer and coded in pyqt4.

I have two files
1. main.py
2. log.csv

I have created a .exe using pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile main.py
```

But while executing, it does not execute because it throws an error cannot find file log.csv in the terminal window

I dunno how pyinstaller works.

Please help me if anyone has already encountered such problem.
Thanks

Comment: Does your program works before you use pyinstaller.exe?

Comment: It works perfectly fine. If i remove the file loading code from main.py and then create .exe , it works and GUI is displayed. only loading the file after creating .exe is the problem. Maybe some directory issues, but I cannot find.

Answer (score 0):

It was a directory issue..
Pyinstaller (if --onefile is used) creates a dist folder which contains the .exe file.
So the application searches for the file in the same directory, but i had the file in a different directory.

And also I had used

```
file = open('log.csv', 'r')
```

without mentioning the exact path.. so the apllicant cant find the file.